# Increment or decrement #variable.value in angular 8 in ngFor

Tags: angular8, ngfor, dynamic-data

i need to increment a number variable with #variable.value
My target is increment or decrement input quantity value, in ngFor of products to buy them.
so this is my code:

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let product of products">

    <ion-card-content>
      {{product.prdNote}}      
      <div class="quantity-container">
        <div class="quantity-buttons">
          <ion-button (click)="quantityInput.value++">-</ion-button>
          <!-- <ion-input type="number" #quantityInput value="quantity" (change)="setQuantity($event)"></ion-input> -->
          <ion-input type="number" #quantityInput [value]="product.prdContainer"></ion-input>
          <ion-button (click)="quantityInput.value++">+</ion-button>
        </div>

        <div class="buy">
          <ion-button (click)="addToCart(product, quantityInput.value)"> <ion-icon name="cart"></ion-icon>Aggiungi all'ordine</ion-button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

i want increment input value number in ng for, every single input i want increment or decrement with #quantityInput.value++, but didn't work for me.

The error is that:

> quantityInput.value Expected a number type

Can i cast #quantityInput.value as number in html ?
There's another way to work?

Thanks

Comment: How does it behaves for you? Do you get any error?

Comment: @Smile i've update the question sorry, the error is quantityInput.value as number

Answer (score 0):

For me, `(click)="quantityInput.value++"` was parsing error. Following code worked for me.
Try

```
<ion-button (click)="quantityInput.value=+quantityInput.value+1">+</ion-button>
```

Here `+` in `+quantityInput.value` is used for casting.

Here is the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhygsc)

Comment: I've tried you answer but the error is the same, quantityInput.value require cast to number

Comment: What's the value of `product.prdContainer`?

Comment: the value start to 0 value

Comment: I have added a working example. Worth trying with plain 'input' and 'button' elements.